# Are there Reinforcement Learning algorithms specialized for the case $\gamma=0$?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, python, algorithm-request

I have a Reinforcement Learning problem where the optimal policy does not depend on the next state (ie gamma equals 0). I think this means that I only need an efficient exploration algorithm coupled with a way to backpropagate the rewards.

I know that contextual bandits are specialized for this situation, except they only work for discrete action space, and I still need my policy network to make complex decisions (train a Deep neural networks, whereas most contextual bandits algorithms I found learn linear policy decisions). I also think deep active learning does not work because I can not trace how the reward is computed (it is not model-based).

Therefore I am looking for algorithms, or ideally a python implementation, that solves RL for continuous action spaces when $\gamma=0$.

Reposted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74073373/3924118).